# Facing Error "Excel can not complete this task with available resources" and another error is "There is no enough memory to complete this action"

Tags: vba, pivot

While refreshing pivot tables in a file I am getting the error: "Excel cannot complete this task with available resources". Another error is: "There is no enough memory to complete this action". May I get any help regarding this error?
I am using this code for refreshing pivot tables in different sheets.

```
pt1.ChangePivotCacheDSC.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase,SourceData:=SourceAddress)
ws6.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotCache.Refresh
```

Comment: How much data is in the Pivot? What is the size of the spreadseheet (in MB)? Are you using 32-bit Excel? How much RAM does your system have?

Comment: This is 30 Mb file. In which 8 sheets have 7 pivot table and 1 is base sheet. Yes I am using 32-bit excel. In error it shows to me that use 64-bit excel. This system have 4 GB RAM

Answer (score 2):

This usually means that either your computer doesn't have enough RAM to store the information needed to complete the calculation, or that Excel's limits have been reached. If you press CTRL + Shift + Escape and look at how much of your computer memory is being used, you can narrow down the options pretty much to Excel being the limiting factor.

EDIT:

Some options to fix this issue could be:

-As ThunderFrame has hinted at, **Install 64-Bit Excel**.

-Perform the calculation on a smaller dataset.

-Install more RAM on your computer.

Comment: I have tested this code with two machines. Facing same error in popup.

Comment: Unless there is a large amount of processing being done by VBA before the snippet you have shown, Tim is right. Try cutting the data set down and see if the problem goes away (just for testing purposes). Also a large number of formulas may have an affect. Would you say it is a large data set?

Comment: Agree. Try moving some data to a new sheet, and disable automatic calculation. Then retry the code to see if it works on just part of the dataset.

Comment: yep there is large amount of data. Approx. 150000 rows are there, and now there is no formula in base sheet. By move data some data to another sheet I ll be able to fetching right records on those pivot tables?

Comment: In that case, if you don't need to refresh the data very often, you could split into two sheets and then execute the code separately.